# RuntimeBinderException: 'IReadDataService ' does not contain a definition for 'GetBySlug'

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

This is a base interface:

```
public interface IBaseDataService<TPage> : IDisposable where TPage : PageBase
{
    Task<TPage> GetBySlug(string slug, 
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken));
}
```

And extend it here:

```
public interface IReadDataService : IBaseDataService<MyPage>
{
}
```

This is interface implementation:

```
public class MyDataService : IMyDataService
{
    private readonly MyDbContext dbcontext;

    public MyDataService (MyDbContext dbcontext)
    {
        this.dbcontext = dbcontext;
    }

    public async Task<MyPage> GetBySlug(string slug, 
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

and finally  I add the implementation to the DI:

```
services.AddScoped<IMyDataService, MyDataService>();
```

Buy when I use it in a controller  the `GetBySlug` found in the interface.

Comment: Please post the full exception details: exception type, message and stack trace of the exception and _all_ its inner exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I add the implementation twice and work fine.

```
services.AddScoped<IMyDataService, MyDataService>();
services.AddScoped<IBaseDataService<MyPage>, MyDataService>();
```